# JQuery - Page resets when using <button> but works fine with <input type="button"

Tags: jquery

I was working on this page yesterday and I found some weird behavior with JQuery. For the form below, the  element the page would correctly load the result, then refresh a fraction of a second later to its default state.

I should also note I'm using JQuery version 1.10.2

```
<form id="scoreCheck">
    <p>
        <label for="score">Score:</label>
        <input type="text" id="score" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="validateScore" value="Check it" />
    </p>
    <p id="answer">The result will go here when the button is pressed.</p>
</form>
```

And the JS / JQuery function (removed the body to save size)

```
$('#validateScore').on('click', function(){
    var scoreInput = Number($("#score").val());

...
...
...

if(tempScore != scoreInput){
    $("#answer").html("<p id='#result'>Invalid Score</p>");
}
    else{
        $("#answer").html("<p id='#result'>Valid Score</p>");
    }
});
```

Is this some kind of bug or did I incorrectly use JQuery when interacting with the button element? Thanks!

Comment: is using a more newer version of jquery is not an option?

Comment: create a fiddle so that all your code can be seen. jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here's the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/JLMkr/

Comment: When i put some value in score say 40...Its not showing anything after validscore??

Comment: Once you press the submit button the information will appear below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should stop that from happening:

```
$('#validateScore').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var scoreInput = Number($("#score").val());
```

Comment: What is Default for the btn?

Comment: In the instance of this question it is to submit the form and go to the form submit page. preventDefault() keeps buttons and anchors from reloading the page. here is the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0):

This is because if the button is within a form, the default behavior is submit.And if you specify its type it will behave like a normal button.

Answer (score 0):

See the reason behind is that when u use input type='button' you are diffrentiating it from the the input type ='submit' thing,which in case of < button > is the default behaviour if its inside the form,now to accomplish this using a < button > or a input type=submit button,u will need to prevent the default behaviour of it ,go through this article

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/